# How to display node labels on graph using networkx and PYG

Tags: networkx, pytorch-geometric

I need to display labels on the graph using networkx.draw function. However it only displays node numbers instead of labels in PYG Data object which is indicated as 'y'.

```
import torch
import torch_geometric
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

edge_index = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 1, 2],
                           [1, 0, 2, 1]], dtype=torch.long)
x = torch.tensor([[-1], [0], [1]], dtype=torch.float)
y = torch.tensor([1,1,1], dtype=torch.long)

data = torch_geometric.data.Data(x=x, y=y, edge_index=edge_index)
g = torch_geometric.utils.to_networkx(data, to_undirected=True)
nx.draw_networkx(g, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

I want to display values in 'y' as the labels for nodes. But it displays node numbers instead.